# When using liquibase, not able to get db result logs

Tags: liquibase, changelog

using liquibase 3.6.2, not able to get DB output logs.
getting queries from change set, but not output, as in,
getting : select max(id) from table; 
but not getting result value.
tried log level as DEBUG,INFO